# How do i output 1-d arrays in a set #(10) per line?

Tags: java

i know i can use many if statements together but i think thats annoying, is there any better way?

```
    for(index=0; index<alpha.length; index++)
    {
        System.out.print(alpha[index]+ "");
        if (index == 9)
            System.out.println();
        if (index == 19)
            System.out.println();
        if (index == 29)
            System.out.println();
        if (index == 39)
            System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if ((index + 1) % 10 == 0)
```

This(`%`) is a rest of division.

Answer (score 1):

Use an inner loop (that iterates from 0 to 9 inclusive).

Comment: This seems much less efficient than Vladimir's method for a large dataset, or is that just me? I suppose given the innerloop size is fixed at 10, the time complexity is within the same order.

Comment: @ianhales: Both solutions need to perform a conditional branch on every iteration, but Vladimir's includes a modulo, which is generally a pretty slow operation.

Answer (score 0):

Use the % operator like this:

```
for(index=0; index<alpha.length; index++)
{
    System.out.print(alpha[index]+ "");
    if ( ( ( index + 1 ) % 10 ) == 0 ) {
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(index=0; index<alpha.length; index++)
{
    System.out.print(alpha[index]+ "");
    if (index % 10 == 9)
        System.out.println();
}
```